# Modify string after defined characters in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm doing some data collecting, the results needs cleaning, here an example of the urls

```
[
  'https://www.test.com/\nElevator',
  'www.test.in\n\nLondon,',
  'https://www.test.de\n\nLocation:',
]
```

As you may guess I need to remove everything after `\n` but some entries don't have that so I must check for that if possible

My code so far

```
if (string) {
    // if not undefiined
    const data = nomd.split(' ')
    // split string by whitespaces
    var regex = new RegExp("(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})");
    // regex from internet
    for (let y in data) {
        // loop
      if (regex.test(data[y])) {
        // url format
        const clean = data[y].substring(0, data[y].lastIndexOf('\n') + 1);
        // not working as expected
        urls.push(clean)
      }
    }
  }
```

EDIT

I end up using this syntax

```
const clean = data[y].trim().substring(0, data[y].trim().indexOf('\n'));
```

Comment: data = data.map(v => v.split('\n')[0])

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression is way overkill and doesn't look to be doing anything useful anyway. Just check if the string includes `\n`, and if it does, slice it (using `indexOf` to find the first occurrence, not the last occurrence, of `\n` - `lastIndexOf` will find the last occurrence).

```js
const data = [
  'https://www.test.com/\nElevator',
  'www.test.in\n\nLondon,',
  'https://www.test.de\n\nLocation:',
];
const cleanData = data.map(
  str => str.includes('\n')
    ? str.slice(0, str.indexOf('\n'))
    : str
);
console.log(cleanData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `replace` the new line `\n` and anything after it with empty space.

```js
const array = [
  'https://www.test.com/\nElevator',
  'www.test.in\n\nLondon,',
  'https://www.test.de\n\nLocation:',
]


const result = array.map(i => i.replace(/\n.*/s, ''))


console.log(result)
```